# Reuse of activity inside other activites

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I have implemented navigation drawer. I have created separate XML as well as separate Activity. Now I wanna use that Activity inside different activities. So we can say that I wanna use that same navigation drawer inside different activities. So I can reduce my code by inflating same code and view inside different activities.

My xml code is like below :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <include layout="@layout/layout_map"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="#4a4a4c"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:background="#393839"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I need your help to achieve this ASAP.

Thanks

Comment: Create BaseDrawerActivity that prepares the Drawer. Extend this activity in other activities and just add the correct fragment in the content_frame

Comment: @SherifelKhatib : But How can I extend that basedraweractivity to other activites?  Because other activites have already extended by ACTIVITY class. N we can't extend more than one class to each class.

Comment: Replace `extends Activity` with `extends BaseDrawerActivity` (or whatever you elect to name it).

Comment: @CommonsWare : Ya I know brother, But I have to extend ACTIVITY to other activities because that activities will contain other things for that I need to extend ACTIVITY. So Drawer will be just one part of that other activites. So whatever XML I have defined above that will be custom view for other activies.

Comment: brother @Jai, check this please: http://www.functionx.com/java/Lesson04.htm

Comment: @SherifelKhatib : brother check my comment given to CommonsWare.

Comment: Please re-read the initial comment. The suggestion is for you to create a subclass of `Activity`, named `BaseDrawerActivity`, that handles your drawer setup. Your activities needing the drawer would then extend `BaseDrawerActivity`, thereby getting both standard `Activity` behavior *and* the drawer setup. This is standard inheritance.

Comment: @CommonsWare Is it standard inheritance? I think it is not that standard given the fact that it is not well-known.

Comment: @CommonsWare : Bro, I got it but can I ask that How can I inflate XML (DrawerLayout View) of BaseDrawerActivity to other activities as other activities will have their own XMLs.

Comment: @Jai: Use `LayoutInflater`, the way you inflate any layout yourself. Use the `View` you get back from `inflate()` to populate your `FrameLayout`. Or, switch to fragments and execute a `FragmentTransaction` to populate your `FrameLayout`. Or, create your `View` hierarchy directly in Java, and use that to populate your `FrameLayout`.

Comment: @CommonsWare : Thanks bro. So If I will inflate that view using addView() method to other activities, Can I access clicklisteners and all other things contain by the BaseDrawerActivity easily? Or May I have to write that all again with other activities also?

Comment: @CommonsWare : Because Drawer will contain many things with listview. So I am confused with that.

Comment: @CommonsWare : Bro I need your help. I have created BaseDrawerActivity and extends it to another activity. On another activity I have used setContentView by passing same parent layout of BaseDrawerActivity. Also inflate child layout of other activity. But I'm not able to access click listeners n all that things which defined in BaseDrawerActivity

Comment: @CommonsWare : I think I will have to write that all code of BaseDrawerActivity to all other activites too. That is what I don't want. So what should I do for that?